Role of the PDF in the conditional expected value of a continuous random variable
I'm looking to develop a more accurate understanding of the role the pdf plays in the conditional expected value of a continuous random variable.
I have previously only calculated this for random variables that are uniformly distributed over the unit interval, and the formula I would use is
\begin{equation*}
    \mathbb{E}[x|x<c]=\frac{1}{F(c)}\int^c_0xdx.
\end{equation*}
A more general formula though is, I believe,
\begin{equation*}
    \mathbb{E}[x|x<c]=\frac{1}{F(c)}\int^c_0xf(x)dx,
\end{equation*}
where $f(x)$ is the pdf.  I know that, for $x\sim U[0, 1]$, $f(x)=1$ but this is where I now get stuck when I move to more general distributions. Why is the pdf not also integrated? It seems as though the formula could be written
\begin{equation*}
    \mathbb{E}[x|x<c]=\frac{f(x)}{F(c)}\int^c_0xdx,
\end{equation*}
but I never see it like that and it seems wrong given that the integration is with respect to $x$.
As a concrete example: suppose $y\sim U[0, t]$, then $f(y)=1/t$ and $F(c)=c/t$. The conditional expected value is
\begin{equation*}
    \mathbb{E}[y|y<c]=\frac{c}{2},
\end{equation*}
but I can only obtain this by doing the following
\begin{equation*}
    \mathbb{E}[y|y<c]=\frac{f(t)}{F(c)}\int^c_0 ydy=\frac{t^{-1}}{(c/t)}\int^c_0ydy.
\end{equation*}
What am I missing? Why isn't the pdf integrated?

When $y \sim U[0, t]$ you have $E[y \mid y < c] = \frac{1}{F(c)} \int_0^c x f(x) , dx = \frac{1}{c/t} \int_0^c x (1/t) , dx = c/2$, so this isn't really a counterexample.

Two problems: (1) You're not clearly distinguishing between a r.v. and its possible values. E.g., $\mathbb{E}[x|x<c]=\frac{f(x)}{F(c)}\int^c_0xdx$ makes no sense, because $x$ is a r.v. on the LHS, but not on the RHS. (2) You're not paying attention to the piecewise nature of the density function. E.g., the p.d.f. of r.v. $Y$ is $f_Y(y)=t^{-1}{\bf1}{0\le y\le t}$, so $\Bbb E(Y\mid Y<c)={1\over F_Y(c)}\int_0^c f_Y(y) dy=c/2$ if $c<t$, and $=t/2$ if $c>t$. NB: The general formula is $\Bbb E(X|A)=\int{-\infty}^\infty x f_{X\mid A}(x) dx,$ where $f_{X\mid A}(x)={f_X(x){\bf1}_{x\in A}\over P(A)}.$

@angryavian it was just an example, not meant to be a counter example. My question is just why is the (1/t) term for the pdf not integrated given that it is under the integral?

@Hal_Incandenza  Because $(1/t)$ is a constant,$^\dagger$ therefore it may be distributed out of the integral.$$\int_0^c x~t^{-1},\mathrm d x = t^{-1}\int_0^c x,\mathrm d x$$ ($\dagger$ or an independent variable.)
